# When you reach the last div in a slideshow, how do you jump back to the first div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a simple slideshow on click, but when i reach the last div of the slideshow and click further everything goes hidden. How do i make sure it jumps back to the first div?

This is how my jquery looks like:

```
function click() {
    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        var $current = $('.work.active');

        $('.work').removeClass('active')
        $current.next().addClass('active')

    })

}
```

So the div elements all have the same class `.work`.
Only 1 of them is  `'active'`

Here is the HTML where u can see i gave every div the same class, only one is `active`:

```
<section>
    <div class="work active">
        <section id="workTxt">
            <h1>Dynamic Infographic</h1>
            <p>This is a dynamic infographic that i made for a school assignment. The infographic contains of some
                data
                about 5 different airports. U can compare the total amount of passengers, total flights and the
                amount
                of cargo an airport had to handle. </p>
        </section>

        <section id="workImg">
            <a href="http://st392522.cmd19a.cmi.hanze.nl/pae5/">
                <div><img class="workIMG" src="img/infographic.png" alt="infographic"></div>
            </a>
            <div><img src="img/infoCol.png" alt="infographicColors"></div>
        </section>
    </div>



    <div class="work">
        <section id="workTxt2">
            <h1>My very first website!</h1>
            <p>This is my very first website i made. U can learn even more about me here, it contains of some
                general
                information about me.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="workImg2">
            <a href="http://st392522.cmd19a.cmi.hanze.nl/pae1/">
                <div><img class="workIMG" src="img/eerste.png" alt="First Website"></div>
            </a>
            <div><img src="img/eersteCol.png" alt="FirstColors"></div>
        </section>
    </div>



    <div class="work">
        <section id="workTxt3">
            <h1>Delivery site for a client</h1>
            <p>This is a delivery website i made for a friend. It's just fictional but it works :).</p>
        </section>

        <section id="workImg3">
            <a href="http://st392522.cmd19a.cmi.hanze.nl/pae2/">
                <div><img class="workIMG" src="img/delivers.png" alt="Delivery Website"></div>
            </a>
            <div><img src="img/deliverCol.png" alt="deliveryColors"></div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="work">
        <section id="workTxt4">
            <h1>Redesign</h1>
            <p>This is a design I made in Adobe XD. I made some changes to <a
                    href="http://www.massageontspanningdeventer.nl/index.php"
                    style="text-decoration: none; color:#F5FF63; font-weight: 400;">this</a>
                site. I wanted to improve it looking at the design and complexion. </p>
        </section>

        <section id="workImg4">
            <a href="https://xd.adobe.com/view/9d326937-d1b0-4997-4fee-27b2965afde1-eb03/?fullscreen">
                <div><img class="workIMG" src="img/redesign.png" alt="Redesign"></div>
            </a>
            <div><img src="img/redesignCol.png" alt="redesignColors"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
<div><img src="img/next.png" alt="NEXT" id="next"></div>
```

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a check to see if it's null or not before changing it.

```js
function click() {
    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        var $current = $('.work.active');

        $('.work').removeClass('active')

        if ($current.next() !== null) {
          $current.next().addClass('active')
        } else {
          $current.parent().first().addClass('active')
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: everything still dissapears for some reason

Comment: The else does `$current.parent().first().addClass('active')`? I edited my answer.

Comment: You should edit your post to show the HTML too then.

Comment: @dub seems `.parent()` won't work unless they're actually in a parent element. Are you sure those `<div>`s are inside another `<div>`, or like a `<body>` or `<html>` or something?

Comment: It would seem like `$current.next() !== null` isn't evaluating to false then. Troubleshoot that and see if there's a hidden empty element or something somewhere. Use `console.log` to test too.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be an empty element.. Does it help if i send u a link to the website?